# make command not working

Tags: kali-linux, kernel-modules

```
/rtlwifi_new# make && make install
make -C /lib/modules/4.12.0-kali2-amd64/build M=/root/rtlwifi_new modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.12.0-kali2-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:58: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am trying to increase the link strength of my WiFi using these commands:

1. `git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new`
2. `cd rtlwifi_new`
3. `git pull`
4. `make`
5. `sudo make install`
6. `sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be`
7. `sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=0`
8. `sudo iw dev wlan0 scan | grep signal`
9. `sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be`
10. `sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=1`
11. `sudo iw dev wlan0 scan | grep signal`

Earlier the `make` command worked successfully, but for some reason I reinstalled my Linux and now I am not able to use it, showing the above mentioned error.

Comment: You followed the instructions given by the Kali Linux documentation with regards to what packages to install before starting? https://docs.kali.org/development/recompiling-the-kali-linux-kernel

Comment: No,why i need to recompile my kernel?
just i want to know about the error,earlier i was able to use the make command.

Comment: That's not what I said. I asked whether you had read the documentation with regards to what packages were needed.

Comment: no,what will i need?

Comment: Read the link you've been given. You're using Kali which isn't a beginners' distribution so you shouldn't need too much hand-holding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the development tools and the headers of your kernel:

```
apt install build-essential
apt install linux-headers-4.12.0-kali2-amd64
```

Comment: It worked,thank you! i have mismatched the version earlier.